# Pandas split a column in data-frame and get headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a pandas data-frame with column 'A'

```
dfc = pd.DataFrame( {"A": ['AB=0.246154;ABP=39.3908;AC=3', 'AB=0.3;ABP=9.95901;AC=2;AF=0.333333', 'AB=0;ABP=0;AC=6;AF=1;AN=6;AO=86', 'AB=0.461538;ABP=3.51141;AC=2']})
```

I want to split column 'A' in the data-frame and get new data-frame like,

```
    A   AB  ABP AC  AF  AN  AO 
0   AB=0.246154;ABP=39.3908;AC=3    0.246154    39.3908 3   None    None    None
1   AB=0.3;ABP=9.95901;AC=2;AF=0.333333 0.3 9.95901 2   0.333333    None    None
2   AB=0;ABP=0;AC=6;AF=1;AN=6;AO=86 0   0   6   1   6   86
3   AB=0.461538;ABP=3.51141;AC=2    0.461538    3.51141 2   None    None    None
```

I tried to split the data-frame column using,

```
dfc.A.str.split(';', expand = True)
```

But it gives new data-frame like,

```
             0            1     2            3     4      5
0  AB=0.246154  ABP=39.3908  AC=3         None  None   None
1       AB=0.3  ABP=9.95901  AC=2  AF=0.333333  None   None
2         AB=0        ABP=0  AC=6         AF=1  AN=6  AO=86
3  AB=0.461538  ABP=3.51141  AC=2         None  None   None
```

How add headers to columns using text before "=" in column and add this new data-frame to original data-frame?
Is there pythonic way to do these two operations in one line?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `extractall`

```
e = dfc.A.str.extractall('([^;]+)=([^;]+)')
pd.Series(e.values[:, 1], [e.index.get_level_values(0), e.values[:, 0]]).unstack()

         AB      ABP AC        AF    AN    AO
0  0.246154  39.3908  3      None  None  None
1       0.3  9.95901  2  0.333333  None  None
2         0        0  6         1     6    86
3  0.461538  3.51141  2      None  None  None
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following, construct a Series/dictionary for each element in column A after splitting the string properly, the index/key will become the header in the result (use `pd.concat` to concatenate the original column A with the new data frame if needed):

```
dfc.A.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(dict(s.split("=") for s in x.split(";"))))

#         AB       ABP  AC        AF     AN  AO
#0  0.246154   39.3908   3       NaN    NaN NaN
#1       0.3   9.95901   2  0.333333    NaN NaN
#2         0         0   6         1      6  86
#3  0.461538   3.51141   2       NaN    NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
d = {"A": ['AB=0.246154;ABP=39.3908;AC=3', 'AB=0.3;ABP=9.95901;AC=2;AF=0.333333', 'AB=0;ABP=0;AC=6;AF=1;AN=6;AO=86', 'AB=0.461538;ABP=3.51141;AC=2']}
rows = [s.split(";") for s in d["A"]]
data = [dict(cell.split('=') for cell in row) for row in rows]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
```

or

```
d = {"A": ['AB=0.246154;ABP=39.3908;AC=3', 'AB=0.3;ABP=9.95901;AC=2;AF=0.333333', 'AB=0;ABP=0;AC=6;AF=1;AN=6;AO=86', 'AB=0.461538;ABP=3.51141;AC=2']}
dfc = pd.DataFrame(d)

f = lambda s : dict(cell.split('=') for cell in s.split(';'))
df = pd.DataFrame(dfc.A.apply(f).tolist())
print (df)
```

Output:

```
         AB      ABP AC        AF   AN   AO
0  0.246154  39.3908  3       NaN  NaN  NaN
1       0.3  9.95901  2  0.333333  NaN  NaN
2         0        0  6         1    6   86
3  0.461538  3.51141  2       NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def spliter(data):
    pairs = [x.split("=") for x in data.split(";")]
    return pd.Series({key: val for key, val in pairs})


dfc.A.apply(spliter)


         AB      ABP AC        AF   AN   AO
0  0.246154  39.3908  3       NaN  NaN  NaN
1       0.3  9.95901  2  0.333333  NaN  NaN
2         0        0  6         1    6   86
3  0.461538  3.51141  2       NaN  NaN  NaN
```